# Swift Compiler Error: Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'

Tags: swift, recursion, switch-statement, return, nested-function

As you can see from the title, I have a func that returns a 'Bool'. **I use a switch statement to handle the various responses, and (unless I missed something) all of my cases return a 'Bool', but I still get the above missing return error.** I'm also not getting an error requesting I put in a default case because all my enum's cases are handled.

To ensure I didn't miss a break somewhere, I added the line `return false` after the switch statement, but not only did the error remain I also got a warning that the new line would not be reached (which seems to be a contradiction). I get a similar warning if I add the line as a default case in the primary switch too.

This func is nested inside a global func and I'm calling it recursively, so that may be part of the issue. Also, some of my switch cases then include switches, which may be confusing the compiler?

**EDIT:**

Okay, here's a minimal version of `DateCode` with any extraneous methods or similar cases removed, and I've renamed the cases to be more descriptive of their role. It's still hefty, but it has all of the different case types for the switch in question and the error reproduces in exactly the same way. To be comprehensive, the original code remains in full at the bottom of this question.

***Example:***

```
enum DateCode {

    // MARK: - Cases

    case
    empty, regularDirectCase0, regularDirectCase1,
    associatedEnumDirectCase(AssociatedTypeCase),
    associatedIntDirectCase(Int)

    indirect case both(DateCode, DateCode)

    // MARK: - Properties

    var asArray: [DateCode] {
        return balkanize(self).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })  // <-- sorting here is why I'm trying to conform to `Comparable`, which generated the error.
    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    fileprivate func balkanize(_ code: DateCode) -> [DateCode] {
        switch code {
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return balkanize(left) + balkanize(right)
        default:
            return [code]
        }
    }


    static func debalkanize(from codes: [DateCode]) -> DateCode? {
        guard codes.count > 0 else { return nil }

        let first = codes[0]

        switch codes.count {
        case 1:
            return first
        case 2:
            return .both(first, codes[1])
        default:
            let array = Array(codes[1 ..< codes.endIndex])
            if let end = DateCode.debalkanize(from: array) {
                return .both(first, end)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - InternalEnums

    enum AssociatedTypeCase: Int, CustomStringConvertible {

        case first = 0, second

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .first: return "FirstAssociation"
            case .second: return "SecondAssociation"
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions: Comparable

extension DateCode: Comparable { }

func ==(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {
    let leftArraySorted  = left.asArray
    let rightArraySorted = right.asArray

    return leftArraySorted.description == rightArraySorted.description
}

func <(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {

    func evaluate(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {
        switch left {
        case .empty:              return (right == .regularDirectCase0)
        case .regularDirectCase0: return (right == .regularDirectCase1)
        case .regularDirectCase1: return (right == .associatedEnumDirectCase(.first))

        case .associatedEnumDirectCase(let leftType):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .regularDirectCase0, .regularDirectCase1: return false
            case .associatedEnumDirectCase(let rightType):         return leftType.rawValue < rightType.rawValue
            case .associatedIntDirectCase(_):                      return true
            case .both(let first, _):                              return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            }

        case .associatedIntDirectCase(let leftInt):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .regularDirectCase0, .regularDirectCase1,
                 .associatedEnumDirectCase(_):           return false
            case .associatedIntDirectCase(let rightInt): return leftInt < rightInt
            case .both(let first, _):                    return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            }

        case .both(_, let last):
            return evaluate(left: last, right: right)
        }
    }

    if let sortedLeft  = DateCode.debalkanize(from: left.asArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })),
        let sortedRight = DateCode.debalkanize(from: right.asArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })) {
        return evaluate(left: sortedLeft, right: sortedRight)
    }

    // This is only reached when above sorting fails...may produce failures.
    return evaluate(left: left, right: right)

}       

// MARK: - Extensions: CustomStringConvertible

extension DateCode: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .empty:              return "Empty"
        case .regularDirectCase0: return "RegDC0"
        case .regularDirectCase1: return "RegDC1"
        case .associatedEnumDirectCase(let association):
                                  return association.description
        case .associatedIntDirectCase(let value):
                                  return "Int:\(value)"
        case .both(let left, let right):
                                  return "\(left), \(right)"
        }
    }
}
```

***Original Code:***

```
enum DateCode: CustomStringConvertible {

    // MARK: - Cases

    case
    mornings, afternoons, evenings, weekdays, weekends,
    dayOfWeek(DayOfWeek),
    dayOfMonth(DayOfMonth),
    months(Month),
    quarter(FiscalQuarter),
    year(Int)

    indirect case both(DateCode, DateCode)

    case empty

    // MARK: - Properties

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .mornings:                  return "Mornings"
        case .afternoons:                return "Afternoons"
        case .evenings:                  return "Evenings"
        case .weekdays:                  return "Weekdays"
        case .weekends:                  return "Weekends"
        case .dayOfWeek(let day):        return day.rawValue
        case .dayOfMonth(let day):       return day.description
        case .months(let month):         return month.rawValue
        case .quarter(let qtr):          return qtr.description
        case .year(let year):            return year.description
        case .both(let left, let right): return "\(left), \(right)"
        case .empty:                     return "empty"
        }
    }

    var asArray: [DateCode] { return balkanize(self).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }) }

    // MARK: - Functions

    func matches(from allDates: [Date]) -> [Date] {
    switch self {
    case .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings:
        return matchByTime(period: self, from: allDates)
    case .weekdays, .weekends:
        return matchByDay(period: self, from: allDates)
    case .dayOfWeek(let day):
        return allDates.filter { day.asNum == Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: $0) }
    case .dayOfMonth(let day):
        return allDates.filter { day.rawValue == Calendar.current.component(.day, from: $0) }
    case .months(let month):
        return allDates.filter { month.asNum == Calendar.current.component(.month, from: $0) }
    case .quarter(let qtr):
        return allDates.filter { qtr.rawValue == Calendar.current.component(.quarter, from: $0) }
    case .year(let yr):
        return allDates.filter { yr == Calendar.current.component(.year, from: $0) }
    case .both(let left, let right):
        let leftDates  = left.matches(from: allDates)
        let rightDates = right.matches(from: allDates)
        return leftDates.filter { rightDates.contains($0) }
    case .empty:
        return []
    }
}

mutating func overwriteSection(with otherCodes: DateCode) {
    self.stripOut(any: otherCodes)      // <-- This ensures that as detail change occurs, changes overwrite.

    var codes = Array(Set(self.asArray + otherCodes.asArray))   // <-- converting to set removes duplicates

    if let index = codes.index(of: .empty) { codes.remove(at: index) }
    if let code = DateCode.debalkanize(from: codes) { self = code }
}

/// removes any codes of the same type...
mutating func stripOut(any code: DateCode) {
    let filtered = self.asArray.filter { nonMatch(any: code, against: $0) }

    if let code = DateCode.debalkanize(from: filtered) {
        self = code
    } else {
        self = .empty
    }
}

// MARK: - Functions: Private

/// used by stripOut
fileprivate func nonMatch(any code: DateCode, against: DateCode) -> Bool {
    switch against {
    case .dayOfWeek(_):
        switch code {
        case .dayOfWeek(_):
            return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .dayOfMonth(_):
        switch code {
        case .dayOfMonth(_): return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .months(_):
        switch code {
        case .months(_): return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .quarter(_):
        switch code {
        case .quarter(_): return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .year(_):
        switch code {
        case .year(_): return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings, .weekdays, .weekends:
        switch code {
        case .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings, .weekdays, .weekends:
            return false
        case .both(let left, let right):
            return nonMatch(any: left, against: against) && nonMatch(any: right, against: against)
        default: return true
        }
    case .both(let left, let right):
        return nonMatch(any: left, against: code) || nonMatch(any: right, against: code)
    case .empty:
        switch code {
        case .empty: return false
        default: return true
        }
    }
}

/// allows recursion for `asArray` read-only property.
fileprivate func balkanize(_ code: DateCode) -> [DateCode] {
    switch code {
    case .both(let left, let right):
        return balkanize(left) + balkanize(right)
    default:
        return [code]
    }
}

/// .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings
fileprivate func matchByTime(period: DateCode, from allDates: [Date]) -> [Date] {
    var dates = [Date]()

    let validCodes: [DateCode] = [.mornings, .afternoons, .evenings]
    guard validCodes.contains(where: { $0.description == period.description }) else { return dates }

    let noon = 12
    let evening = 18

    for date in allDates {
        let comp = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)

        switch period {
        case .mornings:   if comp < noon                    { dates.append(date) }
        case .afternoons: if comp >= noon && comp < evening { dates.append(date) }
        case .evenings:   if comp >= evening                { dates.append(date) }
        default:
            print("Error @ DateCode.matchByTime")  // <-- Guard statement above prevents this...
        }
    }

    return dates
}

/// .weekdays, .weekends
fileprivate func matchByDay(period: DateCode, from allDates: [Date]) -> [Date] {
    var dates = [Date]()

    let validCodes: [DateCode] = [.weekends, .weekdays]
    guard validCodes.contains(where: { $0.description == period.description }) else { return dates }

    let weekend = [1, 7]

    for date in allDates {
        let comp = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)

        switch period {
        case .weekdays:
            if !weekend.contains(comp) { dates.append(date) }
        case .weekends:
            if weekend.contains(comp)  { dates.append(date) }
        default:
            print("Error @ DateCode.matchByDay")  // <-- Guard statement above prevents this...
        }
    }

    return dates
}

// MARK: - Functions: Static

static func debalkanize(from codes: [DateCode]) -> DateCode? {
    guard codes.count > 0 else { return nil }

    let first = codes[0]

    switch codes.count {
    case 1:
        return first
    case 2:
        return .both(first, codes[1])
    default:
        let array = Array(codes[1 ..< codes.endIndex])
        if let end = DateCode.debalkanize(from: array) {
            return .both(first, end)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


    // MARK: - InternalEnums: DayOfMonth

    /// Numerical associations start at 1, not 0 (e.g. 1-31, NOT 0-30).
    enum DayOfMonth: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
        case first = 1, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth, fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth, seventeenth, eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twentyFirst, twentySecond, twentyThird, twentyFourth, twentyFifth, twentySixth, twentySeventh, twentyEighth, twentyNinth, thirtieth, thirtyFirst

        var description: String { return "\(self.rawValue)/month" }
    }

    // MARK: - InternalEnums: Month

    /// Numerical associations start at 1, not 0 (e.g. 1-12, NOT 0-11).
    enum Month: String {
        /// Capitalized so that raw value will also be capitalized.
        case Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec

        var length: Int {
            switch self {
            case .Jan, .Mar, .May, .Jul, .Aug, .Oct, .Dec: return 31
            case .Feb: return 28
            default: return 30
            }
        }

        var asNum: Int {
            switch self {
            case .Jan: return 1
            case .Feb: return 2
            case .Mar: return 3
            case .Apr: return 4
            case .May: return 5
            case .Jun: return 6
            case .Jul: return 7
            case .Aug: return 8
            case .Sep: return 9
            case .Oct: return 10
            case .Nov: return 11
            case .Dec: return 12
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - InternalEnums: DayOfWeek

    /// Numerical associations start at 1, not 0 (e.g. 1-7, NOT 0-6).
    enum DayOfWeek: String {
        /// Capitalized so that raw value will also be capitalized.
        case Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat

        var asNum: Int {
            switch self {
            case .Sun: return 1
            case .Mon: return 2
            case .Tue: return 3
            case .Wed: return 4
            case .Thu: return 5
            case .Fri: return 6
            case .Sat: return 7
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - InternalEnums: FiscalQuarter

    /// Numerical associations start at 1, not 0 (e.g. 1-4, NOT 0-3).
    enum FiscalQuarter: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
        case first = 1, second, third, fourth

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .first:  return "1st Qtr"
            case .second: return "2nd Qtr"
            case .third:  return "3rd Qtr"
            case .fourth: return "4th Qtr"
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions: Comparable

extension DateCode: Comparable { }

func ==(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {
//    return left.hashValue == right.hashValue

    let leftArraySorted  = left.asArray
    let rightArraySorted = right.asArray

    return leftArraySorted.description == rightArraySorted.description
}

func <(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {

    func evaluate(left: DateCode, right: DateCode) -> Bool {
        switch left {
        case .empty:      return (right == .mornings)
        case .mornings:   return (right == .afternoons)
        case .afternoons: return (right == .evenings)
        case .evenings:   return (right == .weekdays)
        case .weekdays:   return (right == .weekends)
        case .weekends:   return (right == .dayOfWeek(.Sun))

        case .dayOfWeek(let leftDay):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .mornings, .afternoons,
                 .evenings, .weekdays, .weekends: return false
            case .dayOfWeek(let rightDay):        return leftDay.asNum < rightDay.asNum
            case .both(let first, _):             return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            default:                              return true
            }

        case .dayOfMonth(let leftDay):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings, .weekdays,
                 .weekends, .dayOfWeek(_):  return false
            case .dayOfMonth(let rightDay): return leftDay.rawValue < rightDay.rawValue
            case .both(let first, _):       return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            default:                        return true
            }

        case .months(let leftMonth):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings, .weekdays, .weekends, .dayOfWeek(_),
                 .dayOfMonth(_):          return false
            case .months(let rightMonth): return leftMonth.asNum < rightMonth.asNum
            case .both(let first, _):     return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            default:                      return true
            }

        case .quarter(let leftQtr):
            switch right {
            case .empty, .mornings, .afternoons, .evenings, .weekdays, .weekends, .dayOfWeek(_), .dayOfMonth(_),
                 .months(_):             return false
            case .quarter(let rightQtr): return leftQtr.rawValue < rightQtr.rawValue
            case .both(let first, _):    return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            default:                     return true
            }

        case .year(let leftYr):
            switch right {
            case .year(let rightYr):  return leftYr < rightYr
            case .both(let first, _): return evaluate(left: left, right: first)
            default:                  return false
            }

        case .both(_, let last): return evaluate(left: last, right: right)
        }
    }

// <-- Error code points right here, referring to the `evaluate` func above

    if let sortedLeft  = DateCode.debalkanize(from: left.asArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })),
        let sortedRight = DateCode.debalkanize(from: right.asArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })) {
        return evaluate(left: sortedLeft, right: sortedRight)
    }

    // This is only reached when above sorting fails...may produce failures.
    return evaluate(left: left, right: right)
}
```

Comment: He covered that non-default in the description.

Comment: Have you tried giving the outer switch a **default**?  I do that sort of insertion when I'm arguing with a compiler.

Comment: Is the outer switch exhaustive? If not, it should have a default case. I imagine that error would precede an error about a missing return, but perhaps not. In any case, I would try it as a troubleshooting measure

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys. Yes I have tried a default in the outer switch, but the error persists and I get a similar warning.

Comment: The outer switch is exhaustive...I would get an error otherwise. I've also tried using a default to no avail

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could provide us with a [mcve] (that is, including the definition of `DateCode` and cutting out bits that aren't necessary to reproduce the error).

Comment: DateCode is a pretty large and gnarly enum, but I'll try and replicate the issue with another example...

Comment: Agree with @Hamish : if you include the necessary parts of `DateCode` we can simply put it into playground and play around with it ourselves.

Comment: I'm going to work on a more abbreviated example, but for now I'll include DateCode in the question.

Comment: Your examples do not compile.

Comment: @JAL try now...

Comment: @Hamish...I've included a proper example above the full code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, @Hamish. Now that I've included the missing part (and the static debalkanize func) the error is gone. I wrote this example in the playground, and so it seems to be compiling with no error...

Comment: @JamesLingo Huh, weird. Have you tried cleaning your build folder?

Comment: Fixed placement issue (poor copy and pasting, sorry). I thought the error was being generated by the internal func originally...if you see where the error points to, can you help me spot why it's expecting a return before the if let?

Comment: @JamesLingo The only error I can get is in your "original code", and that's because `DateCode` doesn't conform to `Hashable` – I assume that's fixed in your actual project? Apart from that, I simply cannot reproduce your problem, so cannot offer any advise on how to solve it. Are you getting the error in a playground by any chance? Never use a playground for testing code, they're super buggy and unreliable – always use a full project.

Comment: Yeah in my original code it conforms to hashable...and thanks for the advice on playground, I had only used it for the example I built. Product > Clean cleared out the error, but I thought it was coming back when I built to run tests. Didn't this last time though. Anyhow thanks for your help.